# fechas php listar al mes

Tags: php, date

tengo este proceso no se hay alguna forma para mejorarlo saludos.
Lo que quiero hacer es que pueda elegir una fecha el numero de meses y hacer una lista dependiendo de la fecha que se inserto. este yo lo hice pero quiero saber si hay alguna mejor opcion de hacerlo. me tope con el problema del mes de febrero y asi lo solucione.

```
<?php
$month=36;
$datePrincipal='2022-04-30';
$date = new DateTime('2022-04-30');
$ultimodia=explode('-',$datePrincipal);

//echo $calculo;
for($x=1;$x<=$month;$x++){

    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
    echo '<br>'; 


    if($date->format('m')=='01')
    {
        if($date->format('d')<='31' && $date->format('d')>='29'){
            $date->modify('last day of +1 month');
        }
    }else{
            $date->modify('+1 month'); 
            if($date->format('d')!=$ultimodia['2'])
            {
               $fechaanterior=explode('-',$date->format('Y-m-d'));
               $fechaanterior=$fechaanterior[0].'-'.$fechaanterior['1'].'-'.$ultimodia['2'];
               $date=new DateTime($fechaanterior);
            }
    }    
      
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si usas la clase `DateTime`, practicamente no tienes que hacer pre-operaciones manuales.

El siguiente código está basado en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34896101/1545868) del sitio en inglés.

Dentro del ciclo:
1- Se calcula el mes siguiente, el 1ro del mes.
2- Luego se calcula qué es menor: el día de la fecha dada o la cantidad de días del mes. 
3- El resultado de lo anterior se le agrega a `$dt`

```php
<?php
$month = 36;
$datePrincipal = '2022-03-30';

$dt = new DateTime($datePrincipal);
$cur_day = $dt->format('j');
while($month--) {
    $dt->modify('first day of +1 month'); // 1ero del mes
    $day = min($cur_day, $dt->format('t')); // Día actual o ultimo día de mes
    $dt->modify('+'. $day-1 .' days');
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Lo anterior imprime:

```
2022-04-30
2022-05-30
...
2023-01-30
2023-02-28
2023-03-30
...
2024-02-29
...
2025-02-28
2025-03-30
```